# Can't delete profile on certain SE sites

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, deleted-accounts

It seems that I can't delete my account from certain SE sites.

I have for many years had several accounts I don't use and am at the moment only active on Physics while I wish to keep a profile on only a few others.

On the user profile pages on the sites, there is a button called `Edit Profile & Settings`. After clicking the side menu gives several options, one of which is `Delete profile`... But on some sites this button is just gone.

For example I am unable to delete my account on [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com), [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com) and [Lifehacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com) (this latter one is in beta).

How come that some sites are trying to hang extra much on to me? How do I delete my account on those?

Comment: You cannot delete your profile if you have at least 2 questions/answers/votes on that site. You can only contact a moderator.

Comment: In [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/10002/steeven?tab=topactivity) and [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/12328/steeven?tab=topactivity) Steeven didn't post any question/answer.

Comment: @Arulkumar in [lifehacks.se], he casted 3 upvotes. In server fault, he casted 1 upvote. may be more than that and retracted. not sure for SF but sure in LH

Comment: your serverfault points to [music.se] where he has 5 casted votes

Comment: I see. It will be a longer process with contacting moderators, I hear. Thank you for the answers.